# Vitest error when using jest.mock: jest is not defined

Tags: jestjs, vite, vitest

I have a project where it's using Vitest with Jest and React Testing Library. I have made the configuration for unit tests and it's working properly. However when I want to do a `jest.mock` on a library/file/React component I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: jest is not defined`

Here is my configuration:

```js
// setupTests.ts

import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';
import { expect } from 'vitest';

expect.extend(matchers);
```

```js
// vitest.config.ts

/// <reference types="vitest" />

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        include: ['**/*.test.tsx'],
        setupFiles: 'setupTests.ts',
    },
});
```

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "setupTests.ts",
        "vitest.config.ts",
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

For mocking, I know you can do `vi.mock` but I prefer using `jest.mock` since I'm used to doing that setup, is this even possible?

Comment: _"it's using Vitest with Jest"_ - in what sense? They're two _different_ test runners.

Comment: My question is not valid, as you pointed out, these are two different test runners. I got confused with the text `jest` included in the RTL package name. So I thought the package needed to run with `jest`. I stared at this issue for too long lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitest is not jest. You aren’t using jest. No it’s not possible, but vi.mock and jest.mock do the same thing because the API is similar.

Check the docs for mocking https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#functions

Comment: Ah you're right! I failed to realize this, I guess I got confused with the text `jest` being included in the RTL package name, so I thought it needed to run with jest for some reason. Yes, these are two different test runners.